# Another way to say "cooked to perfection"?

Tags: idioms

Something that means the same thing, but not worded like that. Thanks.

Comment: 'a point'  – a French term used to describe food cooked just to the point of perfect doneness.

Comment: I have been searching for a good alternative to this phrase for years, have not found much. Neither have the makers of restaurant menus, because they pretty much all use it.

Comment: Josh's answer is so spot on, the question almost deserves to be reopened only on that basis... but the question is only in the title, there's no other explanation, no description, no research. Nothing. How can I possibly cast my vote in favour?

Comment: Alex, could you at least explain the situation where you would use this phrase or idiom? Could you say why you are looking for an alternative, and tell us which ones you discarded. Yes, I know it may seem superfluous, but on EL&U we prefer detail and your question has been put on hold for being too broad. Ironically, in the three hours  your question was open, it attracted exactly one answer. That is the definition of an oxymoron, me thinks.

Answer (score 4):

There is the idiomatic expression ***[be done to a turn:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+done+to+a+turn)*** :

> - To be done for exactly the right amount of time necessary or desired. *My goodness, these steaks are so flavorful and have been done to a turn!*

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: It's a great answer, really clever.

Comment: BUT, if only you had asked the OP to provide a bit more detail I'm sure the question would not have been closed for being too broad, and if it had been closed, it would be easier to reopen.

Comment: Why don't you try to fix the question? Improve on it. Actually, the OP has been a member of Stack Overflow for 4 years. So, he's not so wet behind the ears.

Comment: It's been closed for being too broad, that's the trouble. The question consists of exactly seven words. Someone so experienced as yourself, should be the first to help users "fix" their questions, you must have known that the question didn't stand a hell's chance.